# Action<T> is different event Action<T>?

Tags: c#

```
public class TestA
{
    public event Action<int> updateEvent;
    ...
    if(updateEvent != null)
    {
        Actin<int> tempEvent = updateEvent;
        updateEvent(1);
    }
}

public class TestB
{
    public Action<int> updateEvent;
    ...
    if(updateEvent != null)
    {
        Actin<int> tempEvent = updateEvent;
        updateEvent(1);
    }
}
```

however `event Action<T>` is eventQueue au

use same and resutl same. What is more good? (i like TestB. Because simple using.)

Comment: What is the purpose of `tempEvent`?

Comment: What's the point of `tempEvent`? - it looks like a broken attempt at protecting from nulls, but a) It should be outside of the `if`, and b) it should then be used for the `if` and the invoke.

Comment: To be thread-safe you should perform the assignment **before** you check for null, in a multithread environment your event can be changed after your _if_ but before the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The `event` modifier is useful to prevent an assignment. What does it mean? If that's a callback with many handlers attached you may want to prevent that someone simply write:
`myObject.UpdateEvent = null` or something like that. With event they can't do that. Take a look at [Learning C# 3.0: Master the fundamentals of C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx).
The code you use to call the event isn't bad but not so useful, if you assign the delegate to temporary variable you may want to be somehow thread-safe (someone could unhook after your null check) so you should do it **before** the check:

```
Action<int> tempEvent = updateEvent;
if (tempEvent != null)
 tempEvent(1);
```

A little side note: if you use events you may want to follow .NET Framework patterns and guidelines, take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx)

Comment: As a side note, with newer c# versions you can write your null check on a single line as: tempEvent?.Invoke(); ;

Answer (score 1):

To the compiler, the difference is that the event cannot be invoked except by the declaring class (like a private member). You can use either in the same way.

To design, events should represent their namesake, i.e. events. Think of a Delegate as just the type or signature of methods. You would declare a class to have an event (of type Action), and you would add (subscribe) to that event other Actions (or methods that can be cast to an Action).

Furthermore, it is common practice to create events of a type that inherits from `EventHandler<T>`

Answer (score 1):

An event is just a delegate with some access wrappers.

The problem with your `TestB` is that because the `updateEvent` delegate is public, ANYONE can fire the delegate, not just the class owning it.

Defining it as an Event as in your `TestA`, client code can only subscribe or unsubscribe to the event, they cannot fire it.

ps. You do not need your tempEvent delegates.

Comment: [Delegate/Event Race conditions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx).  To add to Gaz's answer, events can only be raised by the classes that define them.  That is, a derived class cannot raise an event defined in its parent class